# PIng a dialup modem using a phone number?

Tags: ping, modem, gate, dial-up

The company I work for has a gate that people have to enter a code to get it. The gate call-box is hooked up to a landline.

The instructions for the call-box say that it has a built-in modem, and that it can connect to the internet. I want to connect to the call-box to get the log files for all the access codes that have been entered recently so I can update which codes are still active.

I know the phone number of the phone line that the gate is connected to, but I don't know what its IP address is (or if it even has one). Does anyone know how I could use the phone number to ping the call-box's modem? I'm just trying to connect to the call-box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would inspect it physically. Does it have an Ethernet cable, or is it wireless? I'm not sure what a land line is unless you're referring to an Ethernet cable - I'm too young perhaps. Figure out which router it's communicating with would be your first step.

Once you know the range that the router than communicate with, e.g. `192.168.1.(1-150)`, you can write a simple script to ping all possible ranges. Record which ones you get a response from. I'm sure there is a specific port that the call-box listens on. The next step after pinging the IP addresses is to try out that specific port for each one. The one that responds to the correct port is probably your man.

Answer (score 0):

A Landline is a "Plain Old Telephone Service" AKA: POTS. it's A Phone Line. and For the Ping Part, I Would Suggest Using a Modem On Your PC, Hit Settings(In Windows 10 / 11 / 8) -> Connections -> Dial-up, Connect Modem to PC, Call Box Number, and go to Network? you may need a Username and Password.